# Import for flask app not recognized by heroku

Tags: python, heroku, import, flask

I am trying to use a .py file that I wrote called "sentence" as an import to index.py. 
They are both in the app's main/home folder. To import, I am saying

```
import sentence
```

And the app works fine when I test in Komodo. But when I push to heroku, my application becomes an error page. The logging addon I have shows that the error is

```
ImportError: No module named sentence
```

I have tried numerous solutions suggested on many different places, and none have worked. I have tried adding __init__.py to the folder. I have tried reinstalling flask to my application and my computer. I have tried moving files to and from /static thinking maybe my files are static resources, but to no avail.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Can you share your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. At least for my situation. I forgot that linux and windows treat capitalization in filenames differently. Upon refactoring some elements of the app, I renamed 'Sentence' to 'sentence.' I discovered this by pulling a fresh repo on a different machine. To fix it, I moved the offending file out of the local repo folder, committed and pushed, then added it back in, committed and pushed. Went back to working as soon as I did that.

If you're having the same issue and this didn't solve it, I'm sorry! Get in touch with me and maybe by the time you're reading this I'll have more experience and can help you better than I helped myself.